# Improve performance of the procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, try-catch

I am writing a stored procedure which is going to be used for a sync in every 4 minutes. It is just a test case and I need to capture the exception in it as well. Is there any other way to use try and catch block in this procedure or this is fine ?

Here is the stored procedure :

```
Create procedure inbound_test 
    @APP1_NO int,
    @APP1_NAME nvarchar (20),
    @APP1_CREATED date,
    @APP1_NO_PK  nvarchar(20)
as
    if exists (select App1_no from test_in1 where App1_no = @APP1_NO)
    Begin try
    Begin transaction
        Update test_in1
        set APP1_NO = @APP1_NO,
            APP1_NAME = @APP1_NAME,
            APP1_CREATED = @APP1_CREATED,
            APP1_NO_PK = @APP1_NO_PK
        where App1_no = @APP1_NO

    Commit transaction
    End try
    Begin Catch
        If @@Trancount > 0
            Throw;
    End Catch

else

If @@ROWCOUNT=0
 Begin try
Begin Transaction

insert into test_in1(
APP1_NO ,
APP1_NAME ,
APP1_CREATED,
APP1_NO_PK
)
 values ( @APP1_NO ,@APP1_NAME , @APP1_CREATED,@APP1_NO_PK)
 Commit transaction
 End try

Begin Catch
 If @@Trancount >0
Throw;
 End Catch
 GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single update or Insert statement will be automatically in atomic transaction. You do not require explicit transaction to start and commit. If that statement is successful then it will be committed else it is already roll backed. Also you do not have explicit rollback in catch which is not necessary.

Also else block does not require another condition 'IF @@Rowcount>0' reason is that if it comes under else block it means that you have record for that value.

Comment: Thanks for your response kannan. If I am not using else statement then Insert statement is not working.I will  remove the Transaction from this procedure. Could you tell me what else I can do to improve the performance as this procedure will be used by a webservice and it is  going to be used for sync in every 4 minutes

Comment: As such it is two simple statements which is update or insert, for update to reach that record faster you can add appropriate index, check execution plan and volume of the records and then decide on that